# Non-core folders

Tags: files

Unfortunately I inherited a directory structure that has additional non-core directories and files in the site root like so:

> includes/
>
> misc/
>
> modules/
>
> profiles/
>
> scripts/
>
> sites/
>
> themes/
>
> **non-core-directory/** (non-core dir, web access via http://domain.name/non-core-directory/index.html)
>
> **non-core-directory-2/** (non-core dir, web access via http://domain.name/non-core-directory-2/index.html)
>
> .gitignore
>
> .htaccess
>
> googlee30f06c3edhehe4d.html (non-core file)
>
> my-page.html (non-core file)
>
> ...other core files.

Is there a clever way to move those non-core directories and files into the sites/domain.name/files/ directory so that they are still accessible from the same URLs but leaving a clean directory structure?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about webserver configuration, and is not Drupal specific. If you can't solve it with mod_rewrite or similar Apache-level means, please make it clear in your question.

Comment: I'm with @Mołot, while you strictly speaking _could_ involve Drupal, why would you want to? Just do it at the server level.

Comment: @Letharion could, but if possible *should not* involve Drupal, for performance reasons. Unless there are additional restriction, all Drupal-related answers will simply be bad ones.

Comment: Yeah, I meant to agreed with you on that. :) Sorry if it came across otherwise.

Comment: There is a module for multi-sites that redirects all XML sitemap file requests which physically should live in the core root `/sitemap.xml` to `/sites/domain.name/files/xmlsitemap/auto-gen-random-folder-name/1.xml` that happens because it's a multi-site and only one sitemap xml is allowed per site. I thought it might be something similar out there for non-core files and folders.

Comment: @Mauro not really - this task is commonly resolved ad webserver level without even turning on PHP engine. Doing it in PHP, or worse, inside Drupal inside PHP, would be terrible performance hit. Trust me, you don't want to try. Been there, done that, got a t-shirt and punch in a jaw for trying.

Comment: Thanks, surely a non-core folder inside there is very tantalising considering that all my non Drupal employers, big or small, like the idea to quickly add files so that are reachable to the World without any CMS that governs the use of their ftp, formats, systems, domains and related services, that's how most of people see the entire web publishing. After that, I can see it is a grey area thanks to @Gisle's [answer](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/100513/non-core-folders/100522#100522)

Comment: @Molot You could have kept the t-shirt and returned the punch. `;)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct place for non-core directories in a Drupal site is below `sites/default/` (or `sites/subsite-name/` if you're site is a multi-site).

Provided you use Apache as a web-server, you can move them there and redirect incoming requests to the old location to the new location with Apache mod_rewrite.

To do this, the lines below should be placed in the Apache host configuration file for your site (usually placed below `/etc` in the file system).

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule non-core-directory/(.*)$ http://example.org/sites/default/new-directory/$1
    RewriteRule non-core-directory-2/(.*)$ http://example.org/sites/default/new-directory-2/$1
    RewriteRule googlee30f06c3edhehe4d.html$ http://example.org/sites/default/googlee30f06c3edhehe4d.html
    RewriteRule my-page.html$ http://example.org/sites/default/my-page.html
</IfModule>
```

Replace `example.org` with your own domain.

This will automatically redirect any URL where the path starts with `non-core-directory/` or `on-core-directory-2/` and the two non-core files to an URL with the path indicated by the rule.

Remember to restart the Apache server after changing its configuration.

Comment: does it have to be specifically in `sites/default/` ? not in `site/domain.name/` ?

Comment: Putting them in `sites/domain.name/` is also OK.